# All web applications not showing in Visual Studio 2019 IIS express

Tags: visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I have created an ASP.NET MVC web application and a Web API project using Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

Now when I set the web app as Startup project and start running it, it builds and open the browser to execute the application. But in the IIS Express in system tray shows only the web app instance, the Web API instance is not showing:

[image]

Previously, it used to show both the instances in IIS express. If I try to run the Web API by typing the Web API instance URL in browser, it doesn't work. Not sure if these are due to Visual Studio updates.

Can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

TIA

Comment: In the Solution Explorer, on the solution node, right-click and select the "Configure Startup Projects" menu item. This allows you to set **both** your API as well as your web app to start when you press F5 in Visual Studio.